# Windows Azure & ASP.NET MVC site deployed on it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

is it possible to deploy asp.net MVC site on windows AZURE platform? I understand we can deploy a WCF service, but what about full site? Will it work? Will it scale (i.e. load balance)?

We're having a project to develop - a donation site, which will be advertised a lot and will receive a lot of traffic. I do want to try AZURE, but is it possible for AZURE to run the full asp.net mvc site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you just need to make sure that MVC dlls are copied to bin folder and MVC project is added as a web role.

Here's a **[tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jnak/asp-net-mvc-projects-running-on-windows-azure)**.

Also take a look here:
[**MVCCloudService**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)

PS. Remember about Azure [prices](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Comment: These days you don't have to do anything special with the MVC binaries.  Just choose the MVC 2 template when you create the project in Visual Studio, and all is done for you.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, MVC2 sites are totally OK for Azure.  Your second question: will it scale (auto-balance) needs more explanation:

If you have more then one compute instance (VM) allocated to your application, MVC2 site will auto-balance provided you haven't made any mistakes with keeping session-information inside the URLs.

However, if you want to automatically adjust the number of compute instances per load on the site, you will either have to write the scaling logic yourself (check this site to get started http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/autoscaling-in-windows-azure/ ) or use a third-party scaling engine like @ http://www.paraleap.com/

HTH